# Django: Menu Controller

Tags: python, django, dynamic, controller

I have a question regarding Django. I created a site and everything works as it is indented to work. The only problem I have is that first of all my `urls.py` and `views.py` files are getting quite bloated (I have one method for every page I have) and that i have for every site one template. I use `{% extend basetemplate.html %}` for making it at least a bit generic. However I find this attempt not really nice. Creating a method inside the `urls.py` and `views.py` in addition to create a template html file seems the wrong attempt.

I already thought about building a big controller and did some googleing but i could not find what i was looking for.

Is there something like a best practice to achieve that? How do you guys handle the amount of templates?

Any advice would be more than welcome :)

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. If you gave an example of some of the views that are repetitive, we might be able to help more.

Comment: I am refering to the fact that a lot is just boilerplate code. especially for the pages that are simply content pages with no context variables...

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to refactor your one application into multiple applications inside your project. Each would have its own `urls.py` & `views.py`.

Answer (score 0):

If all your view does is render a template, then you can use `TemplateView` [directly in your urls.py](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/#simple-usage-in-your-urlconf), and you don't need to define a view for each url.

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^about/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="about.html"), name="about"),
    url(r'^contact/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="contact.html"), name="contact"),
]
```

Other generic class based views might be useful as well. If there was a way to map the urls to the template names programatically (e.g. the template name was `<slug>.html`, you might not even need a url for each template. However, as I said in the comments above, I can't make any specific suggestions without seeing more of your code.

Comment: Please do not put any logic at all into urls.py - even if you're trying to DRY.

Comment: @ChristopherSchäpers I understand that you want to keep logic out of urls, but I would disagree that it is an absolute rule. Django is 'the framework for perfectionists with deadlines', I think the above approach *might* be suitable (as I've already said, I don't know what the OPs views look like so I can't offer any more specific advice).

Comment: What if you have to add authentication to these template views? What about Mixins in general? What about loose coupling (one of django's key principles)? Where is the advantage by using TemplateView.as_view(...) instead of MyView(TemplateView): template_name="blah" ? This is bad advice.

Comment: I see your point, but I would suggest that it's acceptable to define your view when you need to add authentication or a mixin, and use `TemplateView` in urls.py until then. Maybe in a perfect world, `as_view()` would not take any arguments and we wouldn't be able to have this argument. I don't think it's worth arguing about any more. Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory called `views` with the following structure.

```
.../project/views/
.../project/views/__init__.py
.../project/views/feature_one.py
.../project/views/feature_two.py
.../project/views/feature_three.py

# in .../project/views/__init__.py import the others
from .feature_one import *
from .feature_tow import *
from .feature_threee import *
```

Now you can go on and import like before from your views.  You can do the same thing for admin, models, form ..etc.

For templates, break them up, use inclusion tag to include the smaller partial files.  Group them and create a nice directory structure.